# From android 12 onward Candidateview or suggestion list not showing up in custom android keyboard using InputMethodService

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am Using InputMethodService in my own keyboard, now from  android 12 candidateview for suggestion is not showing.

I have checked all changes done from android 12 and 13, and also check logcat for checking any exception throwing , but nothing works out

Comment: Post the code of your onCreateCandidateView, and anything that sets completions and/or directly manipulates its visibility.  However I can tell you that having worked for 4 years in the on screen keyboard industry-  nobody used candidates view, we all just made our own view on top of our keyboard view and managed its visibility ourselves.  The decisions the framework made with it and the relayouts it caused were kind of wonky

Comment: @Override 
public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
        mCandidateView = new CandidateView(this);
        mCandidateView.setService(this);
        return mCandidateView;
    }
For candidateview class I am using below code
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/CandidateView.java

Comment: This may be the same problem as discussed in https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard/issues/901 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246132117